# Android Activity File Naming Conventions

Tags: java, android

I have my app and started by naming the packages that contain .java files things like. com.activity.app

so for instance I have a search activity and it would be under com.search.app

I believe I read somewhere that com is used only in development and you should use another naming convention when publishing. Is there any truth to this and are there any conventions to abide by?

Answer (score 0):

The convention is something like:
com.my_company_name.my_app_name

There's nothing written in stone, really...

Answer (score 0):

Yor package name should be unique as this identifies (and is visible in URL) the app on the Market.

Best practice is to use your internet domain name if you have one.